# Google Sheets' Calculation logic

Tags: date, math, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to work out peoples age best on there date of birthday,

I am currently using this calculation,

```
=YEAR(TODAY())-YEAR(C2)-1 + (MONTH(TODAY())>MONTH(C2)) + (MONTH(C2)=MONTH(TODAY()))*(DAY(TODAY())>=DAY(C2))
```

Instead of using today's date, I need to use 1st September 2011, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
=YEARFRAC(DATE(2011,9,1),C2,3)
```

Comment: This is the best solution! Also, see the [documentation on the formula](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092989?hl=en-GB&rd=1) which also includes an example for age calculation:

_Calculates a person's age by combining the YEARFRAC and TODAY functions, then applying ROUNDDOWN to the result to return the number of years._

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this spreadsheet: https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=pPbcejygf5gZgPjUVvCZqYQ&hl=en#gid=0

Click the Years cell ( `C5` ) and check the formula that uses the birthday date ( `A5` ) and a fixed date ( `B5` ). In your case `B5` would be `2011-09-01`:

```
=IFERROR(IF(( IF((DAY(B5)-DAY(A5))<0 ; -1;0)+(MONTH(B5)-MONTH(A5)))< 0 ; -1 ; 0)+(YEAR(B5)-YEAR(A5)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace every occurrence of TODAY() with DATE(2011,9,1):

```
=YEAR(DATE(2011,9,1))-YEAR(C2)-1 + (MONTH(DATE(2011,9,1))>MONTH(C2)) + (MONTH(C2)=MONTH(DATE(2011,9,1)))*(DAY(DATE(2011,9,1))>=DAY(C2))
```

For a person born on the date in cell C2, this would give what their age will be on Sept 1, 2011.

**Edit:** Or, more simply, try this:

```
=2011-YEAR(C2)-1 + 9>MONTH(C2) + (MONTH(C2)=9)*(1>=DAY(C2))
```

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a [formula to show age as a string from a DOB](http://blog.jezmckean.com/google-sheets-show-age-from-dob/) e.g. `10y 6m`:

`=CONCAT(FLOOR((TODAY() - B2)/365),CONCAT("y ",CONCAT(FLOOR((((TODAY() - B2)/365) - FLOOR(((TODAY() - B2)/365))) * 12), "m")))`